# How to apply table css to this structure?

Tags: css

I have this html markup:

```
<div class="entry-content"><table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th><strong>32nd</strong>  </th>
<th> <strong>Decimal</strong></th>
</tr>
...
```

How I can specify to apply a set of table style specifically to the table enclosed in a entry-content class width?

I have tried this in my .css like this:

```
#entry-content {
  .table {
```

But it does not work.

**EDIT**

It has to be very specific to this structure. i.e. the css must apply to only

```
.entry-content table
```

not

```
.entry-content p table
```

Otherwise the css may stuff up layouts that also uses `table`

Comment: Use `.entry-content table` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this CSS selector.

```
.entry-content table{
   //styles here
}
```

If you want to apply styles to `tr` and `th` use this selector

```
.entry-content table tr{
   //some styles
}

.entry-content table th{
   //some styles
}
```

**Edit**

The above selector selects any table (not just immediate child) that is inside the `.entry-content`, even if the table is inside of another `div`, which is inside the `.entry-content`.

In order to select an immediate child/table of the `.entry-content` use this selector:

```
.entry-content > table{
    //some style
}
```

Comment: FWIW, the 'table' in the second example isn't necessary (given that the TH can't be in anything other than a table to begin with.)

Comment: I agree. That is just an illustration for a beginner to make this more understandable how css selectors work

Comment: @Zafar It is possible to apply it only to structure that table is an immediate child of '.entry-content'? Your answer will cause other structure like '.entry-content p table' to also pick up the css. I have added this observation to the question.

Comment: @AnthonyKong You could use direct [children selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) `>` as: `.entry-content > table`

Comment: no, it is applicable for any `table` inside `.entry-content`. not only immediate child. if your `table` is inside of another `div`, which is inside `.entry-content`, it still applies the style

Comment: @AnthonyKong, and yes, either way.

Comment: @Zafar Do you mind to incorporate Hashem Qolami's comment into your answer? It will address my question and I will accept your answer. Thanks